# With Capybara and Selenium how to do a SHIFT+ click

Tags: ruby, selenium, capybara

I'm trying to test select multiply lines in a table by clicking first element, then click last element with SHIFT. But no luck so far..

I know Selenium has the following to invoke the SHIFT key:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

element.send_keys(Keys.SHIFT)
```

How can I achieve the same desired behavior using Capybara?

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATE** With modern versions of Capybara you should just be able to do

```
last_element.click(:shift)
```

https://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/Capybara/Node/Element#click-instance_method

=============================================

There is no cross driver way to do this in Capybara but when using the selenium driver you can do

```
 page.driver.browser.action.key_down(:shift).click(last_element.native).key_up(:shift).perform
```

*Note I haven't tested that exact code so there may be typos but it should be close

Comment: This saved my @$$ after hours of scouring the docs and should be the accepted answer.  Thank you.

Comment: @sammms This answer was really old. With a recent release of Capybara you should just be able to do `element.click(:shift)`

Comment: thanks for the follow up.  Unfortunately I'm on Rails 4 with an older version of Capybara and this is all I've found that helped.  But your legacy answer was perfect for my legacy code ; )  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

`page.driver.browser.action.key_down(:shift).perform` gives you a state where the key is 'held' and you can then execute clicks.  `page.driver.browser.action.key_down(:shift).perform` then releases the key.  As @Thomas Walpole points out, this is a legacy issue, applicable to Rails 4 (in my case).  In new versions of Capybara `element.click(:shift)` should do the trick.